# sum all value keep same id

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is I have some value using explode, so if I want display value in database using explode, I must use foreach. The problem is I don't want all showing up, because I want sum all the value to keep same id.

```
$customer_sql_query = "SELECT * FROM winner_delivery ";
$customer_sql_result = mysqli_query($connection,$customer_sql_query);
while ($customer = mysqli_fetch_array($customer_sql_result)){

    $ecommercelist = "";
        $snacklist = "";

        if ($customer['ecommercelist'] != "") {
          $ecommercelist = $customer['ecommercelist'];
        }
        else if ($customer['status'] == "delivered") {
          $snacklist = $customer['deliverysnacklist'];
        }
        else {
          $snacklist = $customer['usersnacklist'];
        }

        if ($ecommercelist){
          $ecommercelist_array = explode('~',$ecommercelist);

          $i = 0;

          foreach ($ecommercelist_array as $ecommercelist_row) {

            if ($i % 2 == "1"){
              $alternatecolor = "#EEEEEE";
            }
            else {
              $alternatecolor = "#FFFFFF";
            }  
            $selection_array = explode('|',$ecommercelist_row);
            $selection_entry = $selection_array[0];
            $temp_qty = $selection_array[1];
            $temp_producttitle = $product_ob[$selection_entry]['producttitle'];
            $temp_imageurl = $product_ob[$selection_entry]['imageurl'];
            $temp_weighttitle = $product_ob[$selection_entry]['weighttitle'];
            $temp_productid = $product_ob[$selection_entry]['productid'];
            $count=$count_qty[$selection_entry] += $temp_qty;
            $i++;
            ?>
  <li>
    <div class="picture"><?=$temp_productid ?></div>
    <div class="weighttitle" nowrap>x<?=$count ?></div>
  </li>
  <?
          }
    }
}
```

Actually I have many time adjust to make better, but is the result!

[image]

btw this my database for ecommerlist

[image]

Comment: You'd better provide some `ecommercelist` data for example.

Comment: don't store multiple values in one database field like this.  Your data is de-normalised and harder to query. Probably you need a separate table for these values with a foreign key to the winner_delivery table. You should study entity-relationship design and database normalisation, and learn how to correctly structure your tables

Comment: thanks guys,maybe i have learn more about entity relationship deisgn and database normanlisation,